# Python game with pygame syncronization problem

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a space invaders game in python with the pygame library. I have a file where I store the record of the player, and at the end of each match, there is a function that checks if the player beat his record, and if that is true, the value in the record file is changed with the score of the last match and the player will see a text "`You lost, new record n points`", or "`You lost, n points`" if it the record is not beaten.

The problem is that this control is made something like 90 times/second (the fps), so the first time the function `is_record()` is launched and if it the function returns true it displays "`You lost, new record n points`", but the other 89 times, the record in the file is changed so the `is_record()` function returns false and display "`You lost, n points`".

So the player always sees "You lost, n points", and never the text "You lost, new record n points" because this last text is displayed only in the first frame of 90.
How can I solve this problem?

The part of my code that needs fixing:

```
    def is_record(points):
        file = open('record', 'r')
        line = file.readline()
        file.close()
        if points > int(line):
            print("1")
            file = open('record', 'w')
            file.write(str(points))
            file.close()
            return True
        else:
            print("2")
            return False

    def redraw_window()
        if lost:
            lost_label = lost_font.render("Hai perso!", 1, (255,255,255))
            WIN.blit(lost_label, (WIDTH / 2 - lost_label.get_width() / 2, 350))
            #print(is_record(player.points))
            if(is_record(player.points) == False):
                final_points_label = lost_font.render(f"{player.points} Punti", 1, (255, 255, 255))
                WIN.blit(final_points_label, (WIDTH / 2 - lost_label.get_width() / 2, 400))
            elif is_record(player.points) == True:
                final_points_label = lost_font.render(f"Nuovo record! {player.points} punti", 1, (255,255,255))
                WIN.blit(final_points_label, (WIDTH / 2 - lost_label.get_width() / 2, 400))
```

Comment: A possible way to fix this problem is to store the game number is the file as well so you can simply check if the game is the same game that the high score is achieved in. Every time the player starts a new game, you change the game number. If you want more information just ask.

Answer (score 1):

Don't rewrite the file in every frame. Set a flag to indicate the file has been updated. Also store the result text for the next loop.

```
fileupdated = False
final_points_label = None
def redraw_window()
    global fileupdated, final_points_label
    if lost:
        lost_label = lost_font.render("Hai perso!", 1, (255,255,255))
        WIN.blit(lost_label, (WIDTH / 2 - lost_label.get_width() / 2, 350))
        #print(is_record(player.points))
        
        if not fileupdated:  # update score file, check high score
            res = is_record(player.points)
            if(res == False):
                final_points_label = lost_font.render(f"{player.points} Punti", 1, (255, 255, 255))
            elif res == True:
                final_points_label = lost_font.render(f"Nuovo record! {player.points} punti", 1, (255,255,255))
            fileupdated = True # prevent rewrite
            
        if final_points_label: # show results
            WIN.blit(final_points_label, (WIDTH / 2 - lost_label.get_width() / 2, 400))
```

When the game restarts, you need to reset the write flag: `fileupdated = False` and the text object: `final_points_label = None`

Comment: i copy your code but i get error: NameError: name 'fileupdated' is not defined, i put it outside of all methods/classes but now the game is not working

Comment: if `redraw_window()` is in a class, you should try `self.fileupdated` and `self.final_points_label`

Comment: it's not in a class, redraw_window() is a function in a function